# Capture minicart configureable product variant info

Tags: cart, configurable-product, mini-cart, magento2.3.5-p2

I just finish install magento2.3.5-p2 with sample data,

I want to understand how to collect variant data of product being added to cart at minicart

The reason for this is to be able for me to push this data into Google Tag Manager event

Screenshot attached below on the part that I require to capture from.

I wanted to get only the configureable product variant selected which is "**Size :S**" and "**Color: Blue**"

I tried tracing the code and able to see that the minicart code are processed at here

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js`

But I am unable to understand how this code works and what is the code to write to get the configureable product variant selected data

Any help is kindly appreciated

[image]

Comment: I am able to find the placement of the cart page at here 'vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html'

Comment: since the page use knockout js I am not able to understand much

Answer (score 1):

Finally able to find ways to obtain the data of the product event by using this code

```
selectedItem = _.find(customerData.get('cart')().items, function (item) {
    return itemId === Number(item['item_id']);
});

var production_options = selectedItem['options'];
```

or alternatively using

```
var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

var options_for_configureable_product = productData['options'];
```

at page

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js`

can try put inside function `_updateItemQty` to test to see that it get triggered during user update item quantity

The options attribute comes from here

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php`

inside the function doGetItemData